# How to display exponent string in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm struggling to display this type of character (the mini `2`) on a Flutter Web screen:
[image]

I've been looking around but without any good results. Is there currently any existing package or method to display this cleanly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of offset property in WidgetSpan.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(children: [
    TextSpan(text: '90 m',),
       WidgetSpan(
          child: Transform.translate(
            offset: const Offset(2, -4),
             child: Text(
                    '2',
                   //superscript is usually smaller in size
                   textScaleFactor: 0.7,
              ),
          ),
        )
  ]),
)
```

or use the Unicode of exponent 2

```
Text("90 m\u00B2"),
```